# C# .Contains not returning correct result

Tags: c#, contains

I have a file containing addresses, I want to check that the addresses are correct. I am comparing the addresses to a list of approved Australian states.

My address file looks something like this:

```
NEW SOUTH WALE 
N S W 2232    
SOUTH AUSTRALI
Victoria      
SA 5158       
Victoria 3136 
Victoria 3029 
N.S.W. 2428
```

And my file with approved Australian states is:

```
NEW SOUTH WALES
QUEENSLAND
SOUTH AUSTRALIA
TASMANIA
VICTORIA
WESTERN AUSTRALIA
```

When I run the code it will return true for 'NEW SOUTH WALE' but it will return false for 'SOUTH AUSTRALI'

Why does it not return true for 'SOUTH AUSTRALI' as it is contained in 'SOUTH AUSTRALIA' ?

Here is the code for reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\C# Project\sampledata.dat");
    var states = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\C# Project\States.txt"); //Reads in states
    int i = 1;
    foreach (string line in lines) //Loops through data
    { 
        if (states.Any(line.Contains)) 
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\C# Project\CorrectAddress.dat", 
                line + Environment.NewLine);
            i++;            
        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\C# Project\IncorrectAddress.dat", 
                line + Environment.NewLine);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you replace the actual values, you'll see that this is precisely what it should do: `"SOUTH AUSTRALI".Contains("SOUTH AUSTRALIA")` which is obviously false

Comment: Since the original code before Liam's correction *obviously doesn't compile*, it's clearly not the *actual code*, nor a [mcve] created to demonstrate the issue. Who knows if this code *even exhibits the same problem*?

Comment: The code does compile?

Comment: @Liam - unterminated string constants don't

Comment: @user3394486 the code works. You are checking for the value `"SOUTH AUSTRALIA"` inside `"SOUTH AUSTRALI"`

Comment: @Liam yes you are. You can call it just fine.

Comment: @Liam - yes, so the code the OP placed in the question *didn't compile*. I'm not sure what the understanding problem is here

Comment: I have literally no idea what your getting at @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my code does compile so I'm not sure what your issue is?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if thats the case why does "NEW SOUTH WALES" inside "NEW SOUTH WALE" return true then?

Comment: @user3394486 your strings are in the wrong order! Remove all this code, just create a single string array and a single line. You'll see that what you typed will never return partial strings

Comment: @user3394486 what Damien is saying is that the code you *originally posted* (it has subsequently been fixed by other people) was invalid, and indeed it was; but since it has now been fixed, best if we all move on from that...

Comment: Additionally, it would help if you'd provide a [mcve] (ready to copy/paste/compile/run, not just a Main method), hard-code all the inputs (there aren't many, and unless you believe file access is relevant, it's an extra pain) and write the output to the console (again, file access makes it harder to help you).

Comment: Apologies all, I'll make sure code is formatted correctly next tine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code If you replace the actual values, you'll see that this is precisely what it should do:

```
"SOUTH AUSTRALI".Contains("SOUTH AUSTRALIA")
```

which is obviously false.

You are looking for *states* that are included in the lines. Using the original data, the following code won't print anything because nothing matches:

```
var lines=new[]{"NEW SOUTH WALE","SOUTH AUSTRALI"};
var states = new[]{"NEW SOUTH WALES","SOUTH AUSTRALIA"};

foreach(var s in lines)
{
    if (states.Any(s.Contains))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    }
}
```

If you wanted to find lines that partially match states you shoudl reverse the calls.

```
foreach(var s in lines)
{
    if (states.Any(state=>state.Contains(s)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
NEW SOUTH WALE
SOUTH AUSTRALI
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over lines in your foreach loop, so eventually, you'll have a value of `s = "SOUTH AUSTRALI"`. Now look at your code:

`if (states.Any(line.Contains))` - which reads as "Does any item in states satisfy the criteria that "SOUTH AUSTRALI" fully contains it?"

The answer of course is no, because no state name that you provided fits fully into that string.

If you change that condition check to:

`if (states.Any(x=>x.Contains(line)))` - now you are asking "Does any item in states satisfy the criteria that it contains "SOUTH AUSTRALI" inside of itself?". SOUTH AUSTRALIA does, and this returns the expected result.

As an aside, the code your posted originally does not return true for "NEW SOUTH WALE", for the same reason.